# Can you put additional data with URL to QRcode but on goint on the URL the data will not be passed along

Tags: qr-code

Is there a way to encode data into QR so that without special readin you wont get the full data.

ex. http://url/path/to/page;moreData is in QR code. When scanning the code it will offer to redirect to http://url/path/to/page but the moreData part will not be represented in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible by simply saving a URL and to QR code. For example if you save a URL(eg:https://setools.xyz/url-encoder/) and data(eg: I like this page) in QR code, then when you open an URL by scanning a QR code then the data must be in URL params for get requests. POST is not possible as a link(a pure text) doesn't post any data.

Comment: Doesent need to be post. It will be a GET endpoint. Its just i want to add data into the QRcode that only some readers will read, others just get the URL.

Comment: when you say some readers, how do you going to identify those some readers, is there any authentication option available? can you explain clearly.

Comment: Those some readers anre under our control. we knnow that htere is more to the Qrcode than initialy seen.

Answer (score 0):

> without special readin you wont get the full data.

You do not specify how "special" the reader should be, nor exactly how hidden the "extra data" should be.

Your description though seems to be exactly fitting the description of [SQRC by Denso-Wave](https://www.denso-wave.com/en/system/qr/product/sqrc.html). Now, the reader / creation technology for these codes is probably against a fee, up to you to investigate. The method they probably used [has been discussed here](https://fukuchi.org/works/qrhack/qrhack1.html)

If all this is too hidden, you can use the fact that you are in control of readers, and just make your own data structure. Use XML, JSON, a delimiter, .. ?